# Spray Application Run Against a Configuration

Tags: sbt, spray, sbt-assembly

I have a Spray application that I would like to run against a different configuration file. In my resources folder, I have a set of configuration files as:

```
resources
  application.conf
  application.integration.conf
  application.uat.conf
```

With the Play framework, I normally put these files inside the conf folder and I do the following to run the application:

```
sbt -Dconfig.file=conf/application.uat.conf run
```

How can I do this with Spray application structure?

Additionally, how could I jar a spray application using sbt so that I can deploy it to a specific environment and just have a script that takes care of starting and stopping the Spray HTTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how you are packing and deploying your app, but you can try this: by default, `application.conf` will be picked up. Additionally, you can override it when running your app with the `config.resource` property in a similar fashion as `config.file`. Moreover, you can have specific configurations for different environments as you have, and they can include `application.conf`.

All these details are crystal clear in the Akka documentation: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/general/configuration.html#Including_files

As for packaging it, you have several alternatives; two good candidates are [sbt assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) and [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) plugins.

Comment: Cool! I had to just do -Dconfig.resource instead of -Dconfig.file

Comment: I do use sbt-assembly!

Comment: @spark Then it's plain easy: what I usually do is packing the common configuration inside the fat jar and then use an external configuration file that includes the appropriate environment configuration, and contains all the node-specific details. This external config is loaded with `config.resource` property.

Comment: With one of our Play applications, I remember doing sbt -DENV=integration which would automagically pick up all the configuration for that specific environment. How could I do the same here?